# python read/write a file list of files

Tags: python, linux, file

In python 2.7, I need to perform the same operations for a list of file list.

Example, 
      # each file is a file descriptor
      for example, fileX = open("someString", "a")

```
 fileList1 = [file1, file2, file3,file4,file5] 
 fileList2 = [file11, file21, file31,file41,file51] 
 allFilelist = [fileList1, fileList2]
```

When I try to read/write some strings on them I get:

```
 line = item.readline()
 IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

---

```
 # each file in allFilList is a file list 
 allFilList = [ifcxRpsFileNameL, ircxRpsFileNameL, transXRpsFileNameL, ifcxFileNameL, 
 ircxFileNameL, transXFileNameL]
 for eachFileList in allFilList :
    for item in eachFileList :
            #print item.read 
            line = item.readline()
            #for line in :
            print "the line read from ", item, " is " , line
            ll= line.strip("\n").split()
            if len(ll) == 0 :
                print "the file " , item , " is empty \n"
                exit  
            elif len(ll) != TOTAL_ITR :
                print "the len of the file " , item , " is not " , TOTAL_ITR , "\n"
                exit
            else:
                item.write("\n")
                lt = [float(num) for num in ll]
                item.write(min(lt))
                item.write(" ") 
                item.write(sum(lt)/len(lt))
                item.write(" ")
                item.write(max(lt))
                item.write(" ")
                item.write("\n")
                item.close()
                break
```

In response to this comment:

> print out item before you try to read from it and post the output

the output is: `<open file 'ND_ifxc_2010_RPS.dat', mode 'a' at 0x2ba38d1e9558>`

Comment: print out `item` before you try to read from it and post the output, please

Comment: The item printout: <open file 'ND_ifxc_2010_RPS.dat', mode 'a' at 0x2ba38d1e9558>, thanks !

Comment: The file is open for appending, but you're trying to read from it?

Comment: yes, all file contents are numbers, i need to write numbers into each file by appending and then read each file and do some operations on all numbers of each file and write back some results to each file without overwriting previous contents. thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have comes from the fact that the files you have open are opened with mode `'a'`, and therefore, not for reading. As a result, attempting to read from a file not open for reading gives you an error.

You are likely better off storing a list of filepaths, and doing this:

1. open with `'r'` mode
2. read lines
3. based on your conditions, close them, reopen in `'a'` mode and write the required lines.

Hope this helps